# Error in sqoop script

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have written sqoop script to import data from Teradata to Hive. It was running fine as expected , then I added one more parameter to my script given below

`--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager`

what exactly --connection-manager parameter does? I looked into sqoop user guide but no luck

Here is the error I'm getting

```
`Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException): /user/temp_110710/part-m-00002 for client 10.2.68.12 already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)`
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting exception not related to connection manager. It is complaining the file already exists in HDFS.

Try to remove the directory from HDFS that is Hive table location, ex:/user/hive/warehouse/students/) and then execute the sqoop once again. Hope it helps.

Comment: hey i resolved the issue..It was due to use of connection manager without specifying hive libraries..Can you please help me to understand what exactly use of connection manager?